# Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, datatrigger

If I put a DataTrigger in a simple Listbox I get this runtime exception:

> Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource

My listbox without datatrigger (no exception):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EdgedBoards}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelEdgedBoard, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">

            <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

My ListBox with `DataTrigger`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EdgedBoards}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelEdgedBoard, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=EdgedBoardsAdd_UC, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

What's wrong with the latter code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't declaring the style correctly, and so it's being set as the *content* of the listbox - you are manually declaring a list that contains a single style.

You should wrap your existing `Style` element with the `<ListBox.Style>` element to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You added the `Style` *as an item*, you forgot the `ListBox.Style` tags. Since you also try to bind the `ItemsSource` you get the error.